# Silverlight OOB Fullscreen Elevated Trust issue

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I want to run silverlight OOB fullscreen using elevated trust.
I noticed that as long as I check elevated trust, there will be a black secondary window when fullscreen is launched. This black window is only noticeable if I alt+tab out.

Once unchecked the elevated trust, the black window is gone.

Application will be run in full screen, so 1 of the way I thought of to solve this problem is to change the resolution, but I do not know this part.

Anyone can help me to remove the black window, or change the computer's resolution programmatically using COM object?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is something to do with Silverlight running the OOB app under the SLLauncher.exe process. AFAIK there is no way around it - I think shutting the window would perhaps kill the process and the app?

Comment: ya, infact like what u said, if u close the black window it kills the process. my concern is that i deploying on a low end PC so I do not wish that it has any performance issue. Also it will be deployed on kiosk, so I don't wish that suddenly it shows the black screen to users.

Comment: I don't think the black screen ever shows on top of the FS and you are in FS mode so they wont see it on the taskbar. It is annoying tho...